# display two images on the screen together showing both with 50% opacity

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, image-processing

I have 2 images (older and modern maps) and I want to show them as one on the screen. (I next start rotating and dragging corners until they match). My images are 7000x10000 pixels aprox.!!

I have the modifiable image in a picturebox, opacity .5. I tried to place the fixed image (as it is) as the form background image. But I only see the picturebox with the image at 50%. Without an image but with backcolor I see the image 50% and background color 50%. So the background shows through the picturebox. Setting both backcolor and backimage shows the color and not the image.

I then tried to use 2 pictureboxes, equal in size and location, each with an 50% opacity image. I only see the one that has "bringtofront".

I see in Paint.Net image editor when using layers, that it shows 2 images together, without much calculation. So DotNet can do it, but I don't know how. Any help please?

This is my code

```
    Dim imageData As New BldData 
    
    Public Sub CreateImg(fnd As String, fnm As String)
        PiBxForgr.BringToFront()
        PiBxBackgr.SendToBack()
        Me.BackColor = Color.Red
        PiBxBackgr.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        Dim bckgrFileInfo = New FileInfo(fnm) ' on background
        If File.Exists(bckgrFileInfo.FullName) Then
            Dim bitMap = New Drawing.Bitmap(bckgrFileInfo.FullName)
            Dim shownRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height)
            imageData.bitMapBackgr = bitMap.Clone(shownRect, bitMap.PixelFormat)
        End If
        Dim frgrFileInfo = New FileInfo(fnd) ' in foreground
        If File.Exists(frgrFileInfo.FullName) Then
            imageData.bitMap = New Drawing.Bitmap(frgrFileInfo.FullName)
            imageData.shownRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, imageData.bitMap.Width, imageData.bitMap.Height)
            rePaint()
        End If
        imageLoaded = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub rePaint()
        PiBxForgr.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        imageData.bitMapForgr = imageData.bitMap.Clone(imageData.shownRect, imageData.bitMap.PixelFormat)
        PiBxBackgr.Image = SetImageOpacity(imageData.bitMapBackgr, 0.5)
        PiBxForgr.Image = SetImageOpacity(imageData.bitMapForgr, 0.5)
    End Sub
    Private Function SetImageOpacity(image As Image, opacity As Double) As Image
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height)
        Using gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            Dim matrix As New ColorMatrix()
            matrix.Matrix33 = opacity ' from 0.0 to 1.0
            Dim attributes As New ImageAttributes()
            attributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap)
            gfx.DrawImage(image, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes)
        End Using
        Return bmp
    End Function

Class BldData
    Friend bitMap As Bitmap ' bitmap of picture in file, original, rotated or distorted
    Friend bitMapForgr As Bitmap ' bitmap of picture on screen
    Friend bitMapBackgr As Bitmap ' bitmap of picture on back
    Friend shownMap As Rectangle ' part of bitmap shown
    Friend scale As Integer ' total size / shown size
    Friend shownmapOrgWidth As Integer
    ... Properties ....
End Class
```

and the images, modern, dated and program display
[image]

Comment: "without much calculation", yeah well underneath every pixel has to be calculated from the pixels in the layers (including alpha value of these pixels), and the layer blend settings.

Comment: Calculations: Not looping over 70 000 000 pixels to change them, for example

Comment: in other words: library functions that were optimized. a reasonable approach. windows has/had GDI and IDK what it has these days. there's graphics acceleration all over the place, even GPU accelerated graphics. sounds like you want that. perhaps add some more ".net" tags. there's hardly any difference between vb.net and c#, in terms of APIs, but the vb.net tag probably doesn't attract the c# crowd.